# Want to Connect Power Bi with MySQL

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I want to import my data from MySQL but it shows two errors everytime.
Sometimes it shows
**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server. the server was not found or was not accessible. verify that the instance name is correct and that sql server is configured to allow remote connections**
and sometimes it shows
**Internal connection fatal error**
I have allowed remote connection too after watching a you tube video

Comment: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server.` suggests you are trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server, not a MySQL Server which are two entirely different database engines.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, can you please tell me how to solve this. I am new to this. I have downloaded both mysql and microsoft sql on my pc but i don't know which one is working.